# running a java project from command line using classpath issue?

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java project from the command line in linux, my project uses two external jar files. The command that i am givin is

java -classpath -jar bin:common-cli-1.2.jar:BuildFrameworkLibrary.jar com.kpit.goa.common.tools.kivibuild.KIVIBuild

where KIVIBuild is the class that contains the main function. But the error that am getting is:

```
baibhav@baibhav:~/git/KiviBuild/Infra/RepoManagement/BuildManagement/KIVIBuild$ java -classpath bin:common-cli-1.2.jar:BuildFrameworkLibrary.jar com.kpit.goa.common.tools.kivibuild.KIVIBuild
```

Gives

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: com.kpit.goa.common.tools.kivibuild.KIVIBuild. Program will exit.
```

Comment: Is `ParseException` contained inside `common-cli-1.2.jar`?

Comment: `java -classpath ".:bin/common-cli-1.2.jar:bin/BuildFrameworkLibrary.jar" com.kpit.goa.common.tools.kivibuild.KIVIBuild`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following command

```
javac -classpath bin/common-cli-1.2.jar:bin/BuildFrameworkLibrary.jar KIVIBuild.java -d .
```

Do not forget to add dot at the end of command

check is `/com/kpit/goa/common/tools/kivibuild/KIVIBuild.class` exist or not
if yes run the following command

```
java -classpath bin/common-cli-1.2.jar:bin/BuildFrameworkLibrary.jar com/kpit/goa/common/tools/kivibuild/KIVIBuild
```

http://www.linuxheadquarters.com/howto/classpath.shtml

Rather than setting class path every time set it onces in existing classpath variable and just run the java command

Comment: I am still getting the error Could not find the main class: com/kpit/goa/common/tools/kivibuild/KIVIBuild. Program will exit. although KIVIBuild.class is present in the respective folder

Answer (score 3):

You need a path separator e.g.

```
 bin/common-cli-1.2.jar:BuildFrameworkLibrary.jar
```

The colon separates paths to individual jar files. e.g. in the above you're referencing the two files

```
bin/common-cli-1.2.jar
BuildFrameworkLibrary.jar
```

and *also* reference the directory containing your compiled classes e.g. if they're in (say) `target/classes` then use:

```
target/classes:bin/common-cli-1.2.jar:BuildFrameworkLibrary.jar
```

(relative to your current working directory)

Comment: if i use path separator i.e java -classpath bin/common-cli-1.2.jar:BuildFrameworkLibrary.jar... or "." i.e java -classpath .:common-cli-1.2.jar:BuildFrameworkLibrary.jar.., then i get the error of : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/kpit/goa/common/tools/kivibuild/KIVIBuild
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.kpit.goa.common.tools.kivibuild.KIVIBuild. Program will exit. I used bin: as in linux classpath --help suggested this way to include the jar files. Jar files are present in the rootpath of the project.

Comment: Error is : Could not find the main class: com.kpit.goa.common.tools.kivibuild.KIVIBuild. Program will exit.